# How to split a file and assign name to file from the same file

Tags: linux, sh

I have txt file with data in lines. I want to split every line and make it as a new file. But I also want to assign name to the file.
My original file contains number of line and every line has two entries which are tab separated. I want the second entry to be assigned as a file name.
for an example:

```
vivek15 #tab separated# ds104
anni23 #tab separated# ds106
```

I want to split every line as single file and the name of the file should be the second entry in a line that is after tab separated. in this case `ds104`.

Comment: split -l 1 file_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameter expansion to extract the substrings before and after the tab.

```
#! /bin/sh
tab=$(printf "\t")
while read -r line ; do
    value=${line%$tab*}
    file=${line#*$tab}
    printf %s "$value" > "$file"
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks choroba. Your code is working but in the new file only first entry is there I want to retain both entry in new file.

Comment: So write the whole `$line` and ditch `$value`.